# How to set SHADEMODE to D3DSHADE_FLAT in directX 11

Tags: directx-11

in DirectX 9 it is
g_d3dDevice->SetRenderState( D3DRS_SHADEMODE , D3DSHADE_FLAT);
what about the dx11's API

thanks

////////update 1///////

vertex/pixel sharder and light will not make the effect at all.
for example. 3 vectex with red  , green , blue color.
if open FLAT ode , it will fill all triangle with first color, if SMOOTH mode , you will get a colorful triangle using Gouraud Shading.

in vertex sharder i got the vertex color.

in pixel sharder i got the pixel color but has already interpolated.

no light no normal info , it is a 2d programme.

and i don't ask for a method to fill the triangle with same color. I only find the way to using FLAT SHADEMODE.

////////update 2///////

```
struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float2 pos : POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR0;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    nointerpolation float4 color : COLOR0;
};
```

but it is using Gouraud Shading also.

////////update 3///////

I find a topic

[http://www.gamedev.net/topic/621313-directx11-and-smooth-shading](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/621313-directx11-and-smooth-shading/)
author said ”I didn't activate smooth shading in Blender“
but i can't find the keyword in Blender

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using the **nointerpolation** modifier on your vertex data.

```
struct VS_OUTPUT_AND_PS_INPUT
{
    float4 f4Position : SV_POSITION;    
    nointerpolation float3 f3WorldNormal : NORMAL;
};
```

You can also use **nointerpolation** on any vertex data for interesting results.

Comment: Well, thank you for showing him that it's explicitly in his control to do it with the shader. I should have just said this. +1 from me!

Comment: struct VertexShaderInput
{
 float2 pos : POSITION;
 float4 color : COLOR0;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
 float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
 nointerpolation float4 color : COLOR0;
};

but it is using Gouraud Shading also. do i misunderstand something?

Comment: @user2275219 You put it on the `VertexShaderInput` type, not the `VertexShaderOutput` type. So place it on the `COLOR0` in `VertexShaderInput`, not the Output.

Comment: put it on input? I'v tested it just now , and failed.

if  VertexShaderInput { float2 pos : POSITION; }; struct VertexShaderOutput { float4 pos : SV_POSITION; float4 color : COLOR0; };

output.color is desided by pos, so no input color value, so it is can not use FLAT mode?
so , if there is a keyword , i think it must be added on Output.struct .

Comment: nointerpolation only really 'needs' to be put onto the input to the pixel shader.  However, I usually use the same struct for vertex output as I do for my pixel shader input.

Comment: pixel shader can not use keyword "nointerpolation"
or else get a error "error X4568: nointerpolation usage unsupported on ps_4_0_level_9_3"

Comment: well wp8 only support ps_4_0_level_9_3
so does it mean that i can't use FLAT mode in it?

Comment: windows phone 8's PS can't using keywords "nointerpolation"
so seems no method for SHADE MODE FLAT

Comment: To be fair, you didn't mention wp8 in the question. As it stands my answer would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, what you're asking for is the Fixed-Function pipeline. In DirectX 11, all that immediate-mode rendering, fixed-function pipeline stuff has been utterly thrown out the window (you can still get it in older versions of OpenGL and very old versions of DirectX, but you want shiny new DirectX 11). How you draw things now is by writing [HLSL shaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then storing it in Vertex Buffers through [`ID3D11Buffer*` and the related APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476501%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You then call the Device Context's `DrawIndexed` or `Draw` functions.

It's a very big change from the fixed-pipeline stuff and the hard state-machine of older OpenGL and older DirectX.

It may help if you follow [this tutorial](http://www.rastertek.com/tutdx11.html). It will give you a good starting point, and if you understand C++ 11 you can even clean up a lot of the weird pointer stuff by using [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

**EDIT:**
The reason I mentioned the fixed-function pipeline is because SHADEMODE was for lighting calculations performed by the Fixed-Function pipeline on the GPU. Because you are writing your own HLSL shaders to draw things, you do not get to set the "Shade Mode". Rather, you define your own shade mode by writing your own HLSL shader. I wasn't sure if you were still thinking about fixed-function pipeline programming with DX11, so I made sure to be as inclusive as possible in this answer.

Short version: doesn't exist, don't bother. Flat/Smooth shading can be achieved by writing your own shaders obeying the laws of light and physics, [many of which have been done before and simplified and explained for your use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading).
Good luck!

Comment: not the difference between Fixed-Function and Programmable.

most of status API has a instead API.
e.g.

g_d3dDevice->SetRenderState( D3DRS_ZENABLE )
change to _d3dContext->OMSetDepthStencilState
g_d3dDevice->SetRenderState( D3DRS_BLENDOP)
 change to _d3dContext->OMSetBlendState

I find all new API except SHADEMODE.

Comment: @user2275219 SHADEMODE was related to fixed-function pipeline, because it told the shader how to do lighting calculations. In the new version, you do your own lighting calculations. There is no FLAT or SMOOTH shading. Only the shading you provide in the Shaders. Does that make sense?

Comment: no, vertex/pixel sharder and light will not make the effect at all.
for example. 3 vectex with red  , green , blue color.
if open FLAT ode , it will fill all triangle with first color, if SMOOTH mode , you will get a colorful triangle using Gouraud Shading.

Comment: @user2275219 That's what I'm trying to tell you. There is no SMOOTH or FLAT mode anymore, because there's no shader being applied for you. _You apply your own shader, you make your own Gouraud Shading_. The pipeline  is _no longer going to take care of that for you_. Sad, I know, but good when you realize you can do _whatever_ you want with that triangle now!

Comment: 3 vectexes of a triangle with red , green , blue color. how can i fill whole triangle with one color which is the color of first vertex .

in vertex sharder i got the vertex color.
in pixel sharder i got the pixel color but has already interpolated.